# Is there a way to loop this CSS animation or make it start onclick with javascript or any other solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick, css-animations

I have a CSS animation that alternate between 2 divs. So one div comes from the right side on top of the 2nd div and the 2nd div goes 100% of screen width to the right, changes its `z-index` (in this case its translateZ) and comes back to the left on top of the first div and then the first div does the same thing. I just need it to be in a loop or a `onClick` event and I am having trouble doing that.

This is what I have so far:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background-color: aqua;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.broj1 {
  background-color: aqua;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation-name: ante;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.broj2 {
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: pero;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: royalblue;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

@keyframes pero {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    translateZ(5px)
  }
}

@keyframes ante {
  50% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateZ(6px);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/kanvas.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="box" class="box">
    <div class="broj1">
      <h1>Ovo je broj 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="broj2">
      <h1>Ovo je broj 2</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use  `animation-iteration-count: infinite;`

Comment: Thanks, it kind of answers my question, but i would still love to see how would it be done in javascript :D

Comment: you can select that elemnt over querySelector or getElementBy* and set element.style.animationIterationCount = "infinte"